# How can I integrate OWIN Authentication Middleware and Sitecore

Tags: sitecore, owin, single-page-application

I have implemented an MVC Application running with Sitecore. The Startup class of OWIN have implemented following like that:

```
[assembly: OwinStartupAttribute(typeof(WebApplication1.Startup))]
namespace WebApplication1.Web
{
   public class Startup
   {
       public void Configuration(IAppBuilder app)
       {
          ConfigureAuth(app);
       }

       public void ConfigureAuth(IAppBuilder app)
       {
           app.CreatePerOwinContext<AppIdentityDbContext>(AppIdentityDbContext.Create);
           app.CreatePerOwinContext<AppUserManager>(AppUserManager.Create);
           app.CreatePerOwinContext<AppRoleManager>(AppRoleManager.Create);

           app.UseOAuthBearerTokens(new OAuthAuthorizationServerOptions
           {
              Provider = new AppOAuthProvider(),
              AllowInsecureHttp = true,
              TokenEndpointPath = new PathString("/Authenticate")
           });
      }
  }
}
```

I have expected when I submit a username, password and grant_type value is password with method POST into URL http://<>/Authenticate the token bearer return to allows user can log in. Unfortunately, the Sitecore throw content is not found and I cannot figure out the way let the request going to the OWIN Middle Authorization. How can I sort it out?

Comment: You may want to have a read through http://blog.baslijten.com/how-to-add-federated-authentication-with-sitecore-and-owin/

Comment: @jammykam: Many thanks for your comment. Sound it works. I will spend a time to go through it.

Comment: Was this working with Sitecore ?

Comment: @Sivalingaamorthy: I have work around with another solution.

Comment: @Toan Vo, can you suggest the work around, can you share the reference...

Comment: Initial, I have built the OWIN normally. The main part is I have to build the pipeline processor to abort the pipeline of Sitecore.